# Radio button style changes when clicked with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, radio-button

I want the radio button to change when clicked. This is what i have now [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDyzg.jpg)

I want it to change to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCZAQ.png) when clicked

Here's my code: `

```
 const [active, setIsActive] = useState(false)

<div className={`checkbox payment-radio-btn1 ${active ? "checkbox:hover" : "" }`}>
  <input type="radio" value="paystack" name='payment' onChange={handleChange}/>
  <label id='paystack'>Paystack (Debit/Credit Card)</label>
</div>
<div className={`checkbox payment-radio-btn2 ${active ? "checkbox:hover" : "" }`}>
  <input type="radio" value="wallet" name='payment' onChange={handleChange}/>
  <label id='wallet'>Pay with Wallet</label>
</div>
```

Here's my css code

```
.checkbox:hover{
border: 2px solid #00B6F0;
background: #FFFFFF;
}

.payment-radio-btn1{
position: absolute;
width: 406px;
height: 64px;
left: 10px;
top: 128px;
background: #F3F4F5;
box-shadow: 0px 24px 38px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
border-radius: 4px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 6px;
display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is a custom `Radio` element that allows you to represent your radio buttons however you like. In this example we use two emoji, but you could use images, or SVG if you wanted.

```js
function Radio({ checked, onClick, children, on = "✔️", off = "" }) {
  return <div className="radio" onClick={onClick}>
    {checked ? on : off } {children}
  </div>
}
```

We can use the `Radio` elements in our app like this.

```js
function App() {
  const [radio, selectRadio] =
    useRadio(["paystack", "paypal", "wallet"], "paystack")
  return <div>
    <Radio checked={radio == "paystack"} onClick={selectRadio("paystack")}>
      Paystack (Debit/Credit Card)
    </Radio>
    {/* more radio options ...*/}
  </div>
}
```

This is made possible by writing `useRadio` which encodes the radio group logic nicely in a custom hook.

```js
function useRadio(validStates, initState) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initState)
  return [
    state,
    value => event =>
      validStates.includes(value)
        ? setState(value)
        : console.error(`invalid option: ${value}`)
  ]
}
```

Here's a minimal, verifiable example. <kbd>Run</kbd> it below and click some radio buttons to see the application state change.

```js
function App() {
  const [radio, selectRadio] = useRadio(["paystack", "paypal", "wallet"], "paystack")
  return <div>
    <Radio checked={radio == "paystack"} onClick={selectRadio("paystack")}>
      Paystack (Debit/Credit Card)
    </Radio>
    <Radio checked={radio == "wallet"} onClick={selectRadio("wallet")}>
      Pay with Wallet
    </Radio>
    <Radio checked={radio == "paypal"} onClick={selectRadio("paypal")}>
      PayPal
    </Radio>
    <pre>{JSON.stringify({paymentOption: radio}, null, 2)}</pre>
  </div>
}

function Radio({ checked, onClick, children, on = "✔️", off = "" }) {
  return <div className="radio" onClick={onClick}>
    {checked ? on : off } {children}
  </div>
}

function useRadio(validStates, initState) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initState)
  return [
    state,
    value => event =>
      validStates.includes(value)
        ? setState(value)
        : console.error(`invalid option: ${value}`)
  ]
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.radio { cursor: pointer; }
pre { padding: 0.5rem; background-color: #ffc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, this solution is exactly what i need.

Comment: You are welcome! You can use `<input type="radio" ...>` inside of `Radio` if you want. Know that it would have added benefit of accessibility and keyboard controls like standard form elements.

Comment: alright, noted!